# How can two objects with the same mass attract each other?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, newtonian-gravity, spacetime, curvature

According to Einstein's theory of GR, two objects with the same mass won't atract each other, Why i'm saying this? The atraction according to GR happens because the objects with less curvature of space and less time dilatation would follow decelerating in a path of an object with deep space curvature and more time dilatation. This means that two objects with the same time dilatation won't atract each other.
Someone could say "they will add each other time dilatation" but even this won't make them atract each other because still both would dilate time at the same time.
So how could someone explain this?

Comment: "The [harmonic motion] according to [Newtonian mechanics] happens because [the pendulum's initial angle is small]. This means [a pendulum with a large initial angle] won't [move]."

Comment: Your understanding is GR is incorrect.  All masses attract each other.  The sun is attracted to all of the planets such that it orbits around the common center of mass.  This is one of the methods of finding exoplanets.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that the gravitational force is related to time dilation. This is because when the gravitational fields are weak we can use an approximation for the relative time dilation of two bodies $A$ and $B$:

$$ \frac{\Delta t_A}{\Delta t_B} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{2\Delta\Phi_{AB}}{c^2}} $$

where $\Delta\Phi_{AB}$ is the difference in gravitational potential energy between $A$ and $B$. If both objects have the same time dilation that means:

$$ \frac{\Delta t_A}{\Delta t_B} = 1 $$

and consequently that $\Delta\Phi_{AB} = 0$ i.e. the two bodies have the same gravitational potential energy.

But the force on an object in a gravitational field is not given by the potential, it's given by the gradient of the potential:

$$ F = -\nabla\Phi $$

So what matters is not the time dilation of our two bodies, but how the time dilation changes as they move towards each other. In the example you give, the ratio $\Delta t_A/\Delta t_B$ would remain equal to one as the two objects approach each other, but both time dilations would increase. That's why we observe a gravitational force between the objects i.e. because their time dilations change with the distance between them.

Comment: I've removed some comments that were crossing the line into unfriendly territory. Please remember a) to be kind to each other and b) that comments are for commenting *on the post being commented on*, not tangential discussion.